# Sports team management

Tags: project-management, sport

Next season I will take over the organisation of our local bowls team.
The present incumbent uses an arcane spreadsheet and Post-It notes. There must be a better way.

I'm after something to keep track of team members and their preferred playing positions. Also, the fixtures and the team members who are available for each fixture. Then some means of notifying the team of updates - either email or presentation on the web.

It is only a small Sunday afternoon league, so not many members to handle.

I know other teams in our league use [Eteamz](http://www.eteamz.com/) but that seems too feature-limited at first sight.

I am open to the platform on which it runs.  Free would be nice but a small fee would be acceptable.

Comment: Note that this isn't bowls, or even sports, specific, if the requirement is just to "keep track of fixtures and the team members who are available for each fixture". It sounds like a simple contact manager/calendar would do. Maybe you could even use MS Outlook if you already use that for email (or Gmail, etc), else Google for a contact manager/calendar, maybe shared, maybe you do it all. My point is that by re-thinking what you actually want and then rephrasing your question, you should get better response. More people know about scheduling than know about bowls, or even sports. HTH

Comment: You might even get fancy & look for a smartphone app, if you all have Androids. Now, that would be something for the average bowls club :-)

Comment: @Mawg Something like [Best Cricket Scorer](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ganapathy.cricscorer) or [TeamSnap](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamsnap.teamsnap), huh? :)

Comment: Yup, why not? @Chenmunka, look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.net.clubsalive.musgravehillbowls&hl=en  (contact them and ask how to use it for your club). Maybe even http://ibuildapp.com/projects.php?action=info&projectid=724714

Comment: @Chenmunka did you ever find a suitable program?

Comment: One year later, and the answer is "I guess not". Even saying that you did not might fidn an answer be of some small help to others in future. If you did find a solution, then pleas estate it here, in order to help others, just like we tried to help you

Comment: D'oh! I must have missed that. Please acept my apologies. Glad you got an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after something simple, there is [MySportsPlanner](http://mysportsplanner.com/).  This is a Dutch website and although most of the site is available in English, some of the FAQ pages are only available in Dutch.

It is a website where you can register a team.  Members of the team then register and make their availability known.  The captain can then select players for matches, send emails to members, keep statistics and other features.

It is free and simple.  Bowls is not one of the sports in its signup dropdown list, so you would have to go for "other sport" but it should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify "gratis", so [this](http://lawnbowlingmanager.com/), which is [reasonably cheap](http://lawnbowlingmanager.com/pricing.php) (from $20/month), might help.

It is customary to list the features at this point, but they would overwhelm this page. Just check out http://lawnbowlingmanager.com/features.php

It's a lot more than you asked for, but your profile shows that technically you are up for it. What do you think?

Btw,

1. if you don't specify lawn bowling our colonial cousins are liable to think you mean 10 pin bowling
2. you don't say if team members will have accses to it and, if so, whether read only. E.g, maybe they can see fixtures on a web page, or maybe they can update their won availability, etc
3. since you are a s/w guy, this might be a fun project to learn a new language or technology