# Cricket Tournament Management Software

Tags: statistics, sport

Our company is organizing a cricket tournament similar to house matches annually. What I need is to store the details of the matches and analyze the statistics accordingly.

The features I need:

- store the details of the match (total scores, scores of the players,
  bowling statistics)
- analyze performance of the players
- points tables and net run rate

Comment: [What operating system? What budget? Please follow the guidelines when asking](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/353)

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16950/sports-team-management

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Teamer](http://teamer.net/) to do this.

It is available as an app that can be used by team / club members.

Team management [features](https://teamer.net/features) include arranging matches, picking teams, etc.

Also, statistics can be gathered from a web app.